# C# - list to store nullable types

Tags: c#, list

In C# we can declare a list to store int, like

List myList = new List {1,1,2};

I want to store null values as well (nullable type) hence I want to create a list of nullable types. Something like this

```
        List<?int> myList = new List<int> {1,1,2};
```

Above code does not compile. Does .Net supports list of nullable types?

Atul Sureka

Comment: You do understand that having an element within a List that is null is going to create havok on any attempts to loop through it right? Are you 100% sure you really want to put a null object into a List?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, you need

```
List<int?> myList = new List<int?> {1,1,2};
```

1. It's `int?` not `?int`
2. You need the nullable int when you construct it as well as in the variable definition.

As a side note, you can't actually declare a list like `List myList = new List {1, 1, 2};` as there's no non-generic `List`.

Comment: There is `ArrayList` which is non-generic.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `?int` but `int?`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `List<int?> myList= new List<int?>();`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `List<int?> myList = new List<int?> {1,1,2};`?

Answer (score 0):

this compiles

```
List<int?> ints = new List<int?> { 1, 2, 3 };
```